# Programming Android App Online

Tags: android

I'm often away from home but I'd really like to use this time to develop an android application. Is there a possibility to do this in the browser? I heard of Orion, but if I understood it right it is just for normal php websites and stuff.

So is there an android ide for the browser (online) ?

It would be very nice if you could help me :)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you install IDE in PC's away from home? If so, use a Version control system to access your code anywhere.

Comment: No that's the point... I can't always install it.

Comment: So, you need paper and pencil. Fix your ideas when they come. Then update your project when your back at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to write an Android app, I guess you have a device running that operating system.

There is an Android app that allows you to develop native apps directly on the device, in a surprisingly powerful IDE. The app is called AIDE and is available on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=de